# Cannon Pixma MG2200 Scanner detected by sane-find-scanner but not scanimage -L

Tags: debian, scanning, sane

I have a Pixma MG2200 Allinone, I have successfully been able to print, but I cant get the scanner to work. I checked the SANE website and my device is supported, but I cant get scanimage -L to see it... Heres the information I've been able to dig up

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04a9:1760 Canon, Inc.
```

**sane-find-scanner**

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1760 [MG2200 series]) at libusb:001:002
```

I've been at this all morning, and I'm about at my wits end. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although it somewhat late, I'll put it for documentation purposes.
I have added that to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184367/scanimage-does-not-find-scanner-unless-sudoed-but-shows-up-with-sane-find-scan/472894#472894), too.

You should install the fresh programs from Canon in the designated way (`install.sh`), which apart from the drivers, add the `scangearmp2` .
That last one is the program from Canon to use the scaner !!  No SANE program, only their insane one.